# Using non-local exits and advising functions to allow hierarchy in archived items

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm very new to both Emacs and this site so I apologize in advance if my question or methods seem stupid or confusing. I've been tinkering around with Emacs and Emacs lisp the past couple of weeks. More specifically, I have been trying to customize `org-mode` to suit my needs.

The current problem pertains to  the archiving functionality of org-mode. I want to configure the function `org-archive-subtree` such that it retains requisite (user-defined) structure in its archive location (currently it only allows grouping freedom of only one level heading).

To get the desirable result I've had to change the following functions:

ORG-ARCHIVE-SUBTREE:

Reading the org-archive.el file, I was able to find that this function definition did not have any system for archiving complex hierarchy. Fortunately, it seems that most of the problems revolve around the string heading.

I've put a `defadvice` around this function which activates some other defadvices for the following functions, runs the original function within a modified heading binding, then deactivates them.

1. `org-get-valid-level` (used to set the final level of the archive input) - I put a defadvice around it to get the desired result.
2. `org-extract-archive-heading` (used to retrieve heading) - I put a defadvice around it to change its return-type from string to list.
3. `re-search-forward` (used to search if heading exists) - I put a defadvice around it which performs a re-search-forward on a string that iteratively searches for match.

The main problem that arises, it seems, is that "heading" is used in some other places in the function and it needs to be a string there. So I'm get a wrong-type-argument error.

A possible work-around, I was thinking, would be to use condition-case or a throw-catch to avoid the error and return a string back to the throwing point in the function. But I am very inexperienced in coding in general and elisp in particular. Furthermore, I can't find any literature that seems to address this issue. Could anyone please tell me what to do? If there is a better method than what I'm attempting please tell me. Any input will help me greatly.

Code:

```el
(defun level (max)
  (interactive "nEnter Depth:")
  (butlast (org-get-outline-path) (- (org-outline-level) (1+ max))))
;; Eg.
;;'level', when called with an integer input, returns the top 'max' headings in a list
;; *h1
;;  *h2
;;   *h3
;; with max=2 would return ("h1" "h2")   

(require 'org-archive)

(defadvice org-extract-archive-heading (around my-heading activate)
  (interactive)
  (setq ad-return-value (call-interactively 'level)))

;;changes org-archive-heading to reflect max depth

(defadvice org-get-valid-level (around override)
  (setq ad-return-value (1+ (length headline))))

;;changes function to give real level

(defadvice re-search-forward (around search-archive)
  (lambda () (setq count 0)
    (while (ad-do-it (concat "^" (regexp-quote (concat (make-string (1+ count) ?*) " " (nth count headline))) (org-re "[ \t]*\\(:[[:alnum:]_@:]+:\\)?[ \t]*\\($\\|\r\\)")) nil t)
      (setq count (1+ count)))
    (if (= count 0) nil t)))

(defadvice org-archive-subtree (around headliner activate)
  (let (heading)
    (ad-activate 'org-extract-archive-heading)
    (ad-activate 'org-get-valid-level)
    (ad-activate 're-search-forward)
    (setq ad-return-value ad-do-it))
  (ad-disable-advice 're-search-forward 'around 'search-archive)
  (ad-disable-advice 'org-get-valid-level 'around 'override)
  (ad-update 'org-get-valid-level)
  (ad-update 're-search-forward))
```